# nested sub menu navbar issues with highlighting

Tags: html, css

I want to create a nested menu. I have a jsfiddle here:

```
<div id=menu>
  <a class=optie href="#">Nieuws</a>
  <a class=optie href="#">Acties</a>
  <a class=optie href="#">Over ons</a>
  <a class=optie href="#">Webshop</a>
  <span class=optie>
    Webshop
    <span class=submenu>
      <a class=suboptie href="#">Producten</a>
      <a class=suboptie href="#">Winkelwagen</a>
      <a class=suboptie href="#">Afrekenen></a>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9p202jt6/

basically when I am hovering over an item of the menu I want it to be highlighted. regardless if it is text or a link.

The problem is I can't seem to change the background gradient and text color properly while I am hovering over an item...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Answer](https://jsfiddle.net/eb8k0tbo/1/). Is it what you expecting?

Comment: @PankitKapadia yes, I had to change something in my posted code. Can you explain what I did wrong? Post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Below code from CSS:

```
.optie:hover a {
    color: rgb(56,56,56);
}
```

As it will apply on all the `<a>` tags under `.optie` class **when hovered**.

[**Solution**](https://jsfiddle.net/eb8k0tbo/1/)